# Cloth Simulation Rips my mesh

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

When I use the cloth simulation and try to make an animation with it, the mesh is ripped into many layers and pieces for some reason...

Any idea why this is happening?[image]

Thanks

Blend File:
[image]

Comment: Impossible to say for sure based on just this. Generally share your blendfile, or share thorough information about your settings and parameters. 

Generally scale can cause lots of issues so that would be my first thought.

Comment: how do i upload my blend file?

Comment: I added the blend file

Comment: the cloth mesh is too messy. it has double vertices, extra faces, etc. Try to use the planes without thickness for the cloth. You can solidify it later, after the cloth modifier. Also the pinning group is strange. Try to play with simple square sheet with pinned corners to get familiar with cloth, then gradually increase complexity.

Comment: Ok thanks. This cape model I actually didn’t model myself it’s downloaded so I’m not familiar with it. How would I go about cleaning it up for use with the cloth modifier?